# Hibernate JPA inputs entity twice and performs weird behavior

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

So, I have tried to solve this problem for the past 7 days or so, but to no avail. I have the following entities in question. I am working with JPA Repositories in IntelliJ.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class ImageEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "content")
    private byte[] content;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "image")
    private Set<ProductEntity> products;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "image")
    private Set<UserEntity> users;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class LocationEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "post_code")
    private int postCode;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location")
    private Set<ProductEntity> products;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location")
    private Set<UserEntity> users;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<CommentEntity> comments;
```

The point is that there is a user with a profile picture and a location.
The problem is the following: during sign in in my app I have two endpoint active: requestPin and signin. The first is sending the pin to an email address provided, and the second is getting that pin and persisting the user data into a mysql database. This is what happens: when the line that says `userRepository.save(in)` it inputs the instance twice, as is with Location and Image too.
Tried every trick in the book, still inputs it twice.
Here's the endpoint method in full, so I don't miss anything:

```
public UserReturnDTO signIn(int pin){
        UserDbInput user = users.get(pin);
        if(user == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong pin. Try again");
       //UserEntity in = mapper.map(user, UserEntity.class);
        UserEntity in = new UserEntity(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getEmail());
        in.setLocation(new LocationEntity(user.getLocation().getState(), user.getLocation().getCity(), user.getLocation().getAddress(), user.getLocation().getPostCode()));
        if(user.getImage() != null)
            in.setImage(new ImageEntity(user.getImage().getContent(), user.getImage().getType()));

       // ImageEntity image = in.getImage();
        //if(image != null)
        //    image = imageRepository.saveAndFlush(image);

       // var location = locationRepository.saveAndFlush(mapper.map(user.getLocation(), LocationEntity.class));
       // UserEntity please = new UserEntity(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getEmail(), location, image);

        //UserEntity entity = userRepository.save(please);



        UserEntity entity = userRepository.save(in);   //The persist line

        int userLastIndex = userRepository.getLastInsertedIndex();
        //userRepository.deleteById(userLastIndex);
        if(user.getImage() != null) {
            int imageLastIndex = imageRepository.getLastInsertedIndex();
            //imageRepository.deleteById(imageLastIndex);
        }
        int locationLastIndex = locationRepository.getLastInsertedIndex();
        //locationRepository.deleteById(locationLastIndex);
        userRepository.flush();
        return mapper.map(in, UserReturnDTO.class);
    }
```

I don't know what to do. It seems like it's messing with me. Since it inputs twice, I tried removing the last inserted index, so I get only one instance in the end, but when I include the lines `imageRepository.deleteById()` and `locationRepository.deleteById()` suddenly then it inputs only one instance of the entity, respectively. These are the default methods from JpaRepsitory<E, PK>.
I even tried resetting the database, still didn't work.
I generated the classes from my database schema, so I didn't tinker with them. For some reason though, Hibernate mapped my OneToOne relationship from my schema to a @ManyToOne and @OneToMany instead of @OneToOne on both sides of User and Image. I tried changing that too, didn't work. I am running out of options here. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I also don't have any triggers configured in my database.
[Here is the diagram of the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxJnU.png)